# Why is LazyRow key working with hashCode but not item id?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

I display a list of movies from the TMDB API. I have a flow observing my data at anytime and I display my data with a LazyRow.

My movies are clickable and should update a single field from MovieUI when doing so. It works the first time but not the next times. My data is updated in my DB as it should. If I reload my app, the correct data is displayed.

The only method I found to make it work is to use movie.hashCode() but in that case my animation doesn't work anymore. If I use movie.id (which is mapped from the Room entity as a Primary Key), it doesn't work but the animation works.

What do I do wrong?

ViewModel

```
    val viewState: StateFlow<MovieUiStateResult> by lazy {
        observeMoviesUseCase()
            .mapLatest { movies ->
                when {
                    movies.isNullOrEmpty() -> {
                        MovieUiStateResult.Empty
                    }

                    else -> {
                        Log.d("HMM", "List fetched in ViewModel is: $movies")
                        MovieUiStateResult.Fetched(list = movies.toListMovieUI())
                    }
                }
            }
            .flowOn(Dispatchers.Main)
            .stateIn(
                viewModelScope,
                SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
                MovieUiStateResult.Loading,
            )
    }
```

MovieEntity

```
@Entity(tableName = "movies")
data class MovieEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "poster_path") val remotePosterPath: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "local_poster_path") val localPosterPath: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "favourite") val favourite: Boolean = false,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "already_seen") val seen: Boolean = false,
)
```

Object used and displayed in my View

```
@Immutable
data class MovieUi(
    val id: Int,
    val coverUrl: String,
    val isFavorite: Boolean
)
```

View

```
@Composable
fun MovieScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    movies: List<MovieUi>,
    onCardEvent: (CardEvent) -> Unit,
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    val movieListState = remember { MovieListState(listState) }

    LazyRow(
        modifier = modifier,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        state = listState,
    ) {
        items(movies) { currentMovie ->
            key(currentMovie.id) { // Not recomposing except if I use currentMovie.hashCode()
                MovieContent(
                    listOfMovies = movies,
                    currentMovie = currentMovie,
                    onCardEvent = onCardEvent,
                    state = movieListState
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Primary key has autoGenerate = false, can you check if all your movies have different id each?

Comment: I did and yes they do. I have 60 items so far so it was easy to check :)

Comment: Where is `movies: List<MovieUi>` coming from? And how do you update the value of an MovieUi item?

Answer (score 0):

So... In my case, I want to be able to double-click on one element to set it as a favorite or not.
I was doing so:

```
Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectTapGestures(onDoubleTap = {
                            onCardEvent(CardEvent.OnDoubleTap(movie))
                        })
                    }
            ) { // content of my box }
```

My pointerInput key is defined at Unit. It works exactly like a LaunchedEffect: if the key doesn't change, it will keep the first item in its memory.

I just had to go from pointerInput(Unit) to pointerInput(currentMovie)